# RegEx for validating float numbers

Tags: regex, ruby, string, regex-group

I'm making a mortgage calculator for class. I have a method to determine whether or not the value is a float, ditto valid number, ditto integer. If the number is a valid number

I have tried using `if valid_number?(apr) && float?(apr)` which returns true for integers.

```rb
def valid_number?(input)
  integer?(input) || float?(input)
end

def integer?(input)
  /^\d+$/.match(input)
end

def float?(input)
  /\d/.match(input) && /^\d*\.?\d*$/.match(input)
end

apr = gets.chomp

if valid_number?(apr)
  if float?(apr)
    puts "Is #{apr}% correct? Y or n"
  end
end
```

I expect anything that does not contain a decimal to be false for the float? method, but if I don't put a decimal my program doesn't seem to care.

Comment: You rarely want to use `^` and `$` (beginning/ending of *line*) in Ruby regexes, you almost always want `\A` and `\z` (beginning/ending of *string*) instead. Have a look at the [`Kernel#Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) and [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) methods.

Comment: I assume you will not encounter `float?(1.2e3)`. I understand why you may want to confirm certain values are integers (the number of periods over which a loan is to be repaid, for example), but I don't see why you need to determine if a value is a float. If the input is the amount of a loan, for example, just convert it to a float, caring not about whether it was entered as a float or an integer. Using floats for financial calculations is generally a bad idea because of round-off error. That's why we have [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and robust way to do this is to not use a regular expression at all. Why do you care what the string looks like? What you really care about is if Ruby can actually *convert* that string to an int/float. Use the built-in `Integer` and `Float` methods for that:

```
def integer?(input)
  Integer(input)
  true
rescue
  false
end

def float?(input)
  Float(input)
  true
rescue
  false
end
```

And what's the point of checking if the string can be converted if you don't get the converted value at the end? Combine everything:

```
def number string
  begin
    return Integer(string)
  rescue
    return Float(string)
  end
rescue
  nil
end

if num = number input
  # now num is some number type: Fixnum/Bignum/Float
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You might just want to wrap your expression in a capturing group and it would pass float numbers, and fail others.

#### Test Code

```
re = /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/m
str = '1
1000
1.00
1000.00'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

For your testing, you may not need to have a multiline flag and `m` can be safely removed.

#### JavaScript Demo

This snippet shows that we likely have a valid expression:

```js
const regex = /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/gm;
const str = `1
1000
1.00
1000.00`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hCaazj/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Performance Test

This script returns the runtime of a float number against the expression.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const regex = /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/gm;
 const str = `1000.00`;
 const subst = `$1`;

 var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: I like this expression better than the one I am currently using. One thing that I have a question about is the 'm' in `/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/m`

Comment: Note that `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`. I don't think Ruby supports the `g` modifier. Also, providing a JS demo when there's no JS tag is of questionable usefulness.

Comment: Answers the question as written, but you should never need a float regex in Ruby (unless you're doing some very particular formatting stuff, which this asker doesn't seem to need).